# PHP Session Remember Me Functionality

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am making a website that uses PHP sessions for "logging in" and having an account. By default, the user is logged out when they close their browser, due to the cookie expiring. I want to implement a "Remember me" or "keep me logged in" functionality to the website. There are two possible solutions that I have considered.

1. Extend the lifetime of the session cookie so it does not expire when the user closes their browser
2. Add a second cookie with a randomly generated sequence of characters that identifies the user. This key would be associated with the user's id in a database. When the user visited the site, the key/id pair would be retrieved from the database, and if they match, the user would be logged in. Obviously the cookie would be http only.

What are the pros and cons to each type of method and do either pose a severe security risk? Also, is there a better method of approaching this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Extending the session cookie lifetime alone will not help – you’d need to set `session.gc_maxlifetime` higher as well, otherwise the GC might clean up your session files in the meantime. // That being said, you should not use sessions for this (the already mentioned GC being one factor – you’re likely to end up with lots of “orphaned” session files, that still occupy HDD space). Use a different cookie with a safe enough token value to recognize a user that had already logged in before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime of a session cookie depends on the settings in your php.ini (session.timeout and session.gc_maxlifetime).
Pro for that is, that the whole session is remembered (not only login)

See also https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/php-session-does-not-expire-on-closing-browser/6831/2

Remember me should bei done by a cookie that identifies the User because you can handle the lifetime better and it doesn't hold the whole session information.

Depends on what you want to remember.